# Center equation and make big and bold

Tags: horizontal-alignment, horizontal-spacing

When using:

`\begin{center}equation\end{center}`

The equation goes far to the right instead of being centred.

#### Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\def\cd{\ \cdot\ }
\def\eq{\ =\ }
\def\pl{\ +\ }
\def\rarr{\ \Rightarrow\ }
\def\arr{\ \rightarrow}
\def\M{\unit{\ g \cd mol^{-1}}}
\def\pr#1{\begin{flushleft}#1\end{flushleft}}
\def\hed#1{\textbf{\pr{#1}}}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\def\can#1{\cancel#1}

\def\gc{\ g \cd cm^{-3}}
\def\gm{\ g \cd mol^{-1}}
\def\cm3{\ cm^{3}\ }
\def\arr{\ \rightarrow\ }

\def\gc{\ g \cd cm^{-3}}
\def\gm{\ g \cd mol^{-1}}
\def\cm{\ cm^{3}\ }
\def\arr{\ \rightarrow\ }

\usepackage{parskip,amsmath}

% spacy math
%\thinmuskip=3mu
%\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
%\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu

\thinmuskip=5mu
\medmuskip=9mu plus 2mu minus 6mu 
\thickmuskip=12mu plus 5mu minus 5mu

\begin{document}

\hed{
  Moles, Molar Mass, Mass Equations:
}

$ 
  M[molar\ mass] \eq
    n[moles] 
    \cd
    m[mass]
    \\
    \\
$

$
  \displaystyle
  \frac{
    M
  }{
    n
  } 
  \eq
  \frac{
    n \cd m
  }{
    m
  }
  \rarr
  \frac{
    M
  }{
    n
  } 
  \eq
  \frac{
    n \cd \cancel{m}
  }{
    \cancel{m}
  }
  \rarr
  n \eq
  \frac{
    m
  }{
    M
  }
  \\
  \\
$

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
$
  \displaystyle
    n \eq
  \frac{
    M
  }{
    m
  }
$
\end{large}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Bad example of how I got what I wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\def\cd{\ \cdot\ }
\def\eq{\ =\ }
\def\pl{\ +\ }
\def\rarr{\ \Rightarrow\ }
\def\arr{\ \rightarrow}
\def\M{\unit{\ g \cd mol^{-1}}}
\def\pr#1{\begin{flushleft}#1\end{flushleft}}
\def\hed#1{\textbf{\pr{#1}}}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\def\can#1{\cancel#1}

\def\gc{\ g \cd cm^{-3}}
\def\gm{\ g \cd mol^{-1}}
\def\cm3{\ cm^{3}\ }
\def\arr{\ \rightarrow\ }

\def\gc{\ g \cd cm^{-3}}
\def\gm{\ g \cd mol^{-1}}
\def\cm{\ cm^{3}\ }
\def\arr{\ \rightarrow\ }

\usepackage{parskip,amsmath}

% spacy math
%\thinmuskip=3mu
%\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
%\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu

\thinmuskip=5mu
\medmuskip=9mu plus 2mu minus 6mu 
\thickmuskip=12mu plus 5mu minus 5mu

\begin{document}

\hed{
  Moles, Molar Mass, Mass Equations:
}

$ 
  M[molar\ mass] \eq
    n[moles] 
    \cd
    m[mass]
    \\
    \\
$

$
  \displaystyle
  \frac{
    M
  }{
    n
  } 
  \eq
  \frac{
    n \cd m
  }{
    m
  }
  \rarr
  \frac{
    M
  }{
    n
  } 
  \eq
  \frac{
    n \cdot \cancel{m}
  }{
    \cancel{m}
  }
  \rarr
  n =
  \frac{
    m
  }{
    M
  }
  \\
  \\
$

\begin{large}
$
  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
  \displaystyle
    n \eq
  \frac{
    M
  }{
    m
  }
  \\
$
\end{large}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Desired behaviour:

Have the last equation centred and maybe in bold

**The equations are messed up, I'll fix them, but please ignore for now**

#### Update using @DavidCarlisle's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\def\cd{\ \cdot\ }
\def\eq{\ =\ }
\def\pl{\ +\ }
\def\rarr{\ \Rightarrow\ }
\def\arr{\ \rightarrow}
\def\M{\unit{\ g \cd mol^{-1}}}
\def\pr#1{\begin{flushleft}#1\end{flushleft}}
\def\hed#1{\textbf{\pr{#1}}}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathastext}

\def\gc{\ g \cd cm^{-3}}
\def\gm{\ g \cd mol^{-1}}
\def\cm3{\ cm^{3}\ }
\def\arr{\ \rightarrow\ }

\def\gc{\ g \cd cm^{-3}}
\def\gm{\ g \cd mol^{-1}}
\def\cm{\ cm^{3}\ }
\def\arr{\ \rightarrow\ }

\usepackage{parskip,amsmath}

% spacy math
%\thinmuskip=3mu
%\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
%\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu

\thinmuskip=5mu 
\medmuskip=29mu plus 2mu minus 12mu \thickmuskip=42mu plus 5mu minus 5mu

\begin{document}

\hed{
  Moles, Molar Mass, Mass Equations:
}

$ 
  M[molar\ mass] \eq
    n[moles] 
    \cd
    m[mass]
    \\
    \\
$

$
  \displaystyle
  \frac{
    M
  }{
    n
  } 
  \eq
  \frac{
    n \cdot m
  }{
    m
  }
  \rarr
  \frac{
    M
  }{
    n
  } 
  \eq
  \frac{
    n \cd \cancel{m}
  }{
    \cancel{m}
  }
  \rarr
  n \eq
  \frac{
    m
  }{
    M
  }
$

{\huge\boldmath
\[
    n \eq
  \frac{
    M
  }{
    m
  }
\]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the 2nd equation first is a `\cdot` (no spacing change from default), vs `\cd` (the second `\cdot`).

Comment: If you want a centred equation, why not use `\[...\]`?

Comment: Please also note that `large` is not an environment. It works more or less by accident, but you should use `{\large ...}`

Comment: Your non-standard macros will make your source code very hard to read. Please reconsider of they are really that good of an idea.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz when you do it that way, the large affects every other thing below it, doing `\begin{large}...\end{large}` applies it only to the things between them, at least that's my experience.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz doing `\[...\]` doesn't center the equation for me, I tried it already and reconfirmed, it aligns to the left

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz about the user defined functions, I find the normal spacing too close, that why I asked if `mudskip` can be set for all operators, then I wouldn't have to use the user defined functions, I tried adding cdot and equals to mudskip but it didn't work

Comment: I would start by removing all these definitions, it's simply wrong to use  `center` for equations , or to ever  use `\ \ \ ` anywhere. It would be better  to post an example with usable markup and describe how you want the output to change.

Comment: I want to remove the user defined functions but I'm having trouble getting = and cdot into muskip. I was forced to use `\ \ \` as `center, /[.../], \raggedright` all failed to center the last equation, you'll see what I mean if you look at the first screenshot. I have clearly said what I want to do; center the equation, make it big and least importantly to have it in bold. As I have given you all the info and changes to be seen I'm confused how you don't understand what I want to do. For the `\ \ \` it was the only way I could have my equation centred.

Comment: what do you need clarification on @DavidCarlisle?

Comment: of course  `\[` gives you flush left equations as you have specified that non-default option. `\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}`  fleqn== flush left equations

Comment: well, I went through your last question cleaning out `\cd` and `\ ` this question is essentially a duplicate, the answer there covers this.

Comment: oh right of course, I removed that but now the equation goes to the far right like in my first screenshot

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that was just a bonus question, I'll remove it, as you can see from the title, I want the last equation to be centered, big and least importantly bold

Comment: `\large\boldmath\[a=b\]` is a large bold centred equation

Comment: much appreciated @DavidCarlisle, Although your logic about the spacing is completely sound, in practice it is not equal to the spacing in my user defined function \cd. I tested \cd vs \cdot  in the same equation and in the case of \cdot the dot is nearly touching the variables, if you don't believe me try it for yourself

Comment: @Nickotine well of course your \cd has `\ ` more space than `\cdot`  as the muskip setting makes both of them get more space. so no matter how large you make medmuskip your \cd will be wider than \cdot

Comment: yes you're right I increased the value of each number by double, checked and it was much too close, I then tripled all values and the spacing for \cdot remained unchanged...

Comment: I tried your formatting suggestion but the equation goes far out to the right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your original problems:

- The second equation is actually centered, with respect to the page. As the page is much wider than the first line of math, the second line seems to come out flush right. So you have to tell LaTeX to center the second line w.r.t. to the first one.
- The second line is not bold, because there is no bold version of the font chosen.

In the following solution, I did two additional changes:

- slanted font for math variables
- corrected math reasoning in the first line

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Use sf for text and math
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}% helvet has a bold slanted font

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{mathtools}% also loads amsmath
\usepackage{cancel}

\def\pr#1{\begin{flushleft}#1\end{flushleft}}
\def\hed#1{\textbf{\pr{#1}}}

\thinmuskip=5mu
\medmuskip=9mu plus 2mu minus 6mu 
\thickmuskip=12mu plus 5mu minus 5mu

\begin{document}

\hed{Moles, Molar Mass, Mass Equations:}

\( M[\text{molar mass}] = n[\text{moles}]\cdot m[\text{mass}] \)
\medskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}% center the two lines w.r.t. each other
  \(\displaystyle
    \frac{M}{m} = \frac{n\cdot m}{m}
    \Rightarrow
    \frac{M}{m} = \frac{n\cdot \cancel{m}}{\cancel{m}}
    \Rightarrow
    n = \frac{M}{m}
  \)\\[3ex]
  \boldmath\large
  \(\displaystyle
    n = \frac{M}{m}
  \)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I hand over to you;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle +10 to you: you really tried

Comment: yes @DavidCarlisle you really went out of your way to help, again apologies for that headache

Comment: thanks a lot @gernot

Answer (score 5):

You have specfied equations are flush left

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
```

To get a large bold centred equation use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}


\[a\cdot a=b\]

{\huge\boldmath
\[a\cdot a=b\]
}

\medmuskip=50mu


{\huge\boldmath
\[a\cdot a=b\]

\[\frac{a\cdot a}{b}\]
$\frac{a\cdot a}{b}$
$\frac{a\;{\cdot}\; a}{b}$
}

\end{document}
```

Inline fractions use scriptsize numerators which do not get any space for binary operators so if you really need space use `\;` or (better) use `\dfrac` and display style fractions in textstyle

Comment: I removed fleqn, and using your code I still get the same result of the equation going to the far right, I'll show you the output and code, the code will have \cdot vs \cd in the 2nd equation and no matter how big I make the number, \cdot spacing is the same

Comment: @Nickotine I added cdot and wide cdot to this answer

Comment: @Nickotine ah sorry ok mathbin do not get space by default at scriptsize, so you could define `\cd` as `\:{\cdot}\:`

Comment: I'll give it a go thanks for all your effort, much appreciated.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the crappy behaviour I get @davidcarlisle

Comment: @Nickotine the n=M/m is perfectly centred in your code your screenshot makes it look on the right as you only show the left half, but you should use `\[` not `center` [your example with page margin shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IQYe.png)

Comment: that code doesn't have fleqn, alright so it's centred, well then can I get it to centre below and in the middle of the equations above it?

Comment: ???? center means center on the page (or minipage as I showed before) it doesn't mean centre in whatever bit of the screen you crop. Perhaps you want a minipage, or perhaps a tabular with a centred column as wide as its widest entry. I really can't guess @Nickotine

Comment: \;{\cdot}\; still doesn't change anything. Although incorrect `/def/cd{\ \cdot\ }` seems to be the only method that works, I'm going to have to stick with it for that reason

Comment: @Nickotine I show `\;\cdot` changing the spacing in the image above. please stop saying standard latex constructs do not work.

Comment: look at my left aligned equations (without fleqn, not really left aligned, just the behaviour of $..$) why is it so impossible to have the last big equation centred beneath them? The 'real' center just looks silly, so is there no solution? If not then I'm forced to use `\ \ \`

Comment: of course there are solutions but you never previously asked for that, you asked for centering. see gernot's answer @Nickotine

Comment: compare `a\ \cdot\ b` then `{a \;\cdot\; b}` your \cdot does not change the spacing please test it out. I appreciate you have a lot of knowledge but in practice it doesn't work

Comment: that's because I assumed that centred meant centred under my $..$ equations, apologies.

Comment: @Nickotine sigh look at the two fractions at the bottom of the image above which just differ by `\;`.  Do not use `\ ` in math mode, never use `\ \ \ `  anywhere if you hope to get any sort of reasonable behaviour from tex.

Comment: I apologise it seems there is an issue with my editor (I'm using an app on my phone, the \cdot in the other answer also don't change spacing, I'm really so sorry for giving you such a headache